# How do I make an Xcode 4 behavior work?

Tags: xcode4

So I have a custom behavior called "Test", and it's set to ⌘-shift-pgdn. It's supposed to just play the Submarine sound. But when I hit that shortcut, it just plays the usual error sound.

This is a test case for trying to get the Unlock behavior to run a Perforce script to unlock files.

[image]